# Conditionally use a web font based on font-size

Tags: css, webfonts

Can `@font-face` be used to only use a web font if the font is above a given size i.e. my webfont renders very poorly at or below 9px - can I make it fall back to arial at this size?

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to use javascript for this.